# how to show these two matrices commutes

Tags: matrices

could any one tell me how to show $(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E$ and $(A-\lambda E)^{-1}A$ commutes where $\lambda$ is chosen in way such that $(A-\lambda E)$ is invertible?

I tried $I=(A-\lambda E)^{-1}(A-\lambda E)=(A-\lambda E)(A-\lambda E)^{-1}$

comparing the equation we get $$E(A-\lambda E)^{-1} =(A-\lambda E)^{-1} E\dots(1)$$
and $$A(A-\lambda E)^{-1} =(A-\lambda E)^{-1} A\dots(2)$$

now I am thinking of multiplyinf ridesides of both equation:

$(A-\lambda E)^{-1} E (A-\lambda E)^{-1}A=E(A-\lambda E)^{-1}A(A-\lambda E)^{-1}=$

but i am not sure it will help much?

Comment: Your claim seems to be not true. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $E=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\lambda=1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: In this case $(A-\lambda E)^{-1} = I$ and so the question is simply whether $[A,E]=0$ which is clearly true because $AE=EA=0$. What were you driving at? (The result does hold in general, as follows from the line of reasoning I give.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = (A- \lambda E)^{-1}$. You have
$$X(A-\lambda E) = XA-\lambda XE = I$$
What can you say about the commutator of both sides with $XE$?

Comment: I dont understand ...........It seems you have done nothing beyond my progress.

Comment: @Wow Try to compute both sides of [XE, XA-\lambda XE] = [XE,I]. What do you get?  (PS: Can the downvoter please explain?)

Comment: $XEXA-\lambda XEXE-XAXE+\lambda XEXE$

Comment: The $XEXA-XAXE = [XE,XA]$ terms are what you are trying to evaluate, right? And you can save time with the other terms: $[XE, XE] = 0$ automatically!

Comment: Since $E$ is not given invertible how can you consider commutator of $XE$ ?

Comment: @user371231 "Commutator" in the sense of rings, not in the sense of groups! That does not require inverting anything. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E(A-\lambda E)^{-1}A&=(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E(A-\lambda E)^{-1}(A-\lambda E)+(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E(A-\lambda E)^{-1}\lambda E\\
&=(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E+(A-\lambda E)^{-1}(\lambda E)(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E\\
&=[I+(A-\lambda E)^{-1}\lambda E](A-\lambda E)^{-1}E\\
&=[(A-\lambda E)^{-1}(A-\lambda E)+(A-\lambda E)^{-1}\lambda E](A-\lambda E)^{-1}E\\
&=(A-\lambda E)^{-1}A(A-\lambda E)^{-1}E\end{align}$$